# IPv6 Abbreviation(zero blocks compression) logic. I'm using c#

Tags: c#, ip, logic, ipv6, abbreviation

This is a complete un compressed IP address 2001:0008:0000:CD30:0000:0000:0000:0101
I need to compress it like this
2001:8:0:CD30::101
But i was only able to compress the zeroes in blocks like this
2001:8:0:CD30:0:0:0:101
using this code

```
 string output = "";
        string a = textBox1.Text;
        if (a.Length != 39  )
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP please enter the IPv6 IP in this format 6cd9:a87a:ad46:0005:ad40:0000:5698:8ab8");
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((a[i] >= '1' && a[i] <= '9') || (Char.ToLower(a[i]) >= 'a' && Char.ToLower(a[i]) <= 'f') || ((i + 1) % 5 == 0 && a[i] == ':'))
                {
                    output = output + a[i];
                }
                else if ((a[i]=='0' && a[i-1]==':') || (a[i]=='0' && a[i-1]=='0' && a[i-2]==':') || (a[i]=='0' && a[i-1]=='0' && a[i-2]=='0' && a[i-3]==':')) 
                {

                }
                else if (a[i] == '0')
                {
                    output = output + a[i];
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP please enter the IPv6 IP in this format 6cd9:a87a:ad46:0005:ad40:0000:5698:8ab8");
                }
            }

            textBox2.Text = output;
        }
```

Im using c# but i only need the programming logic about how can whole blocks of zeroes be deleted the problem is there could be more then 1 group of blocks containing all zeros in an ip but only one should be abbreviated.

Comment: you only have to remove extra 0's right?

Comment: Yup but prob is if an IP is like this
2001:0000:0000:CD30:0000:0000:0000:a141
then it will be abbreviated like this 
2001:0:0:CD30::a141
and nt like this
2001::CD30:0:0:0:a141
which means in an ip whole blocks of zeros can be compressed to two colons only once
And it must be from where the continued blocks of zeros are more in number like in above example 3 blocks of zeroes were compressed while others were not.

Comment: ok, so the problem is the last "block" which does not follow the rule

Comment: @Balder, see RFC 5952, Section 4.2.3: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952#section-4.2.3, "When there is an alternative choice in the placement of a "::", the longest run of consecutive 16-bit 0 fields MUST be shortened (i.e., the sequence with three consecutive zero fields is shortened in 2001:0:0:1:0:0:0:1). When the length of the consecutive 16-bit 0 fields are equal (i.e., 2001:db8:0:0:1:0:0:1), the first sequence of zero bits MUST be shortened.  For example, 2001:db8::1:0:0:1 is correct representation."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was far more tricky than I expected, but here you got the way to do it with regular expressions:

```
        private static string Compress(string ip)
        {
            var removedExtraZeros = ip.Replace("0000","*");

            //2001:0008:*:CD30:*:*:*:0101
            var blocks = ip.Split(':');

            var regex = new Regex(":0+");
            removedExtraZeros = regex.Replace(removedExtraZeros, ":");


            //2001:8:*:CD30:*:*:*:101

            var regex2 = new Regex(":\\*:\\*(:\\*)+:");
            removedExtraZeros = regex2.Replace(removedExtraZeros, "::");
            //2001:8:*:CD30::101

            return removedExtraZeros.Replace("*", "0");
        }
```

Comment: Thank You Soo Much its works and its awesome but Please can you explain this line
var regex2 = new Regex(":\\*:\\*(:\\*)+:");

What is it actually doing ??

Comment: Hi, as you can see i replaced the "compressed zeros" in the first step with *, to in the second step ( removing the left 0 from blocks) does not messing around.  In the third step I just look for blokcs the regex means, I'm looking for blocks which starts with :*:*, has at least one or more :* blocks and end with a :

Comment: I didn't choose very wise replacing 0 blocks with *, since * is a regexp metacharacter, when using a metacharacter you must escape it with \, but for the string to understand it you must use \\METACHAR. If i would have use "o" instead of "*" the regex2 would have been as simple as: new Regex(":o:o(:o)+:");

Comment: This answer does not rightfully shorten 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334. I added my answer using a system.net class instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to achieve the same result without using `Regex`:

```
public string Compress(string value)
{
    var values = value.Split(",");
    var ints = values.Select(i => int.Parse(i, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
    var result = ints.Select(Conversion.Hex);
    return string.Join(":", result);
}
```

Didn't spend time on micro-optimizations (stackalloc, spans, etc.) but this gives an idea. For reference on optimization, you can look at the implementation of the `IPAddress.Parse` in the .net core. Do mind that result of the `IPAddress.Parse` will give a different result than the example above:

```
Compress        -> 2001:8:0:CD30:0:0:0:101 
IPAddress.Parse -> 2001:8:0:cd30::101
```

This could be "cleaned" up by moving into some object and other ideas.

Edit:

After chatting with one of my colleagues, I spent some time writing an "optimized" version of this. I haven't spent time cleaning up the code, so maybe one of the future edits will be even cleaner.

```
public string Compress(string value)
{
    Span<char> chars = stackalloc char[value.Length];
    const char zero = '0';
    const char colon = ':';
    int index = 0;
    int positionInSegment = 0;
    bool startsWithZero;

    while (index < _originalValue.Length)
    {
        startsWithZero = value[index] == zero && positionInSegment == 0;
        positionInSegment++;
        if (startsWithZero)
        {
            if (index == value.Length - 1)
            {
                chars[index] = zero;
                break;
            }
                        
            if (value[index + 1] == colon)
            {
                chars[index] = zero;
                positionInSegment = 0;
                index++;
                continue;
            }
                        
            positionInSegment = 0;
            index++;
            continue;
        }

        if (value[index] == colon)
        {
            positionInSegment = 0;
            chars[index] = colon;
            index++;
            continue;
        }
                    
        chars[index] = value[index];
        index++;
    }

    return chars.ToString();
}
```

I have also created a public gist for future references:
https://gist.github.com/DeanMilojevic/7b4f1d060ce8cfa191592694b11234d7

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use the System.Net.IPAddress class for this.

For instance parsing a string to an IPAddress object.

```
var tempIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334");
var tempShortenedIPAddress = tempIPAddress.ToString();

// tempShortenedIPAddress  = 2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334
```

Comment: yeah when i posed this question 9 years ago this class was not available :D