# How we can convert IPV6 into abbreviate form in c#?

Tags: c#

Rule for abbreviate: if a complete portion is zero then it can be written as 0 and if two or more consecutive portions are zero they can be ignored for example if we have 
**1234 0000 0000 0000 1212** 
it can be written as 
**1234 :: 1212**

Comment: `agree-gate`? I don't understand why you spelled it like this when you spelled it perfectly fine in your title.

Comment: now is it ok?by the way spelling dosn't matter.

Comment: Is this a string value? Sounds like a simple conditional and replace to me...

Comment: yes it is string type. can you get int type as to much long?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is what you are looking for:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Compress("1234:0000:0000:0000:1212"));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static string Compress(string ip)
{
    var removedExtraZeros = ip.Replace("0000","*");

    //2001:0008:*:CD30:*:*:*:0101
    var blocks = ip.Split(':');

    var regex = new Regex(":0+");
    removedExtraZeros = regex.Replace(removedExtraZeros, ":");


    //2001:8:*:CD30:*:*:*:101

    var regex2 = new Regex(":\\*:\\*(:\\*)+:");
    removedExtraZeros = regex2.Replace(removedExtraZeros, "::");
    //2001:8:*:CD30::101

    return removedExtraZeros.Replace("*", "0");
}
```

*Source: [IPv6 Abbreviation(zero blocks compression) logic. I'm using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170946/ipv6-abbreviationzero-blocks-compression-logic-im-using-c-sharp)

Comment: using namespace missing?
which namespaces should i use?

Comment: The only one you need is `System.Text.RegularExpressions`. Updated answer.

Comment: Its not working
 Error 1 The name 'ip' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Check my answer again. Updated with the main code, that's how you call the `Compress` function.

Comment: In this case feel free to accept is a right answer.